# Checking irreducibility

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra

This is related to [this question.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111404/algorithm-to-check-is-representation-irreducible-algorithm-to-decompose-the-r) Suppose I have an $n$-dimensional representation of a finitely generated group, and I want to know whether it is absolutely irreducible. This can, of course, be done if you are willing to compute the eigenspaces of the generators, but that involves working over the splitting field of the characteristic polynomial (it should, presumably, be the same for all the generators if the representation is reducible), but that is not what I would describe as pleasant. Is there anything more efficient? (note that I can, of course, diagonalize the generators numerically, but I am not sure what this tells me).

Comment: If you know for some reason that your representation is completely reducible, then the double centralizer theorem tells you that the representation is absolutely irreducible if and only if the scalar maps are the only endomorphisms which commute with the representation.

Comment: @PeterMueller what does this actually mean in practical terms?

Comment: Well, you have finitely many invertible matrices $a_i$ in $M_n(K)$. So the common centralizer $C$ of all the $a_i$ (which is the same as the centralizer of the group generated by the $a_i$) is the intersection of the subspaces $C_i$, where $C_i$ is the space of matrices commuting with $a_i$. So $C$ can be computed by simple linear algebra. Of course the scalar matrices are in $C$, and your representation is absolutely irreducible if and only if $C$ isn't bigger.

Comment: The representation $\rho$ of $G$ is absolutely irreducible iff $\rho(G)$ linearly generates the algebra of matrices. So an algorithm is to compute the rank $r_k$ (in the sense of linear algebra) of the subspace spanned by $\rho(B_k)$, where $B_k$ is the $k$-ball, until it stabilizes i.e. $r_{k}=r_{k+1}=R$. Then the representation is absolutely irreducible iff $R=n^2$.

Comment: What I use here, in the irreducible case: The $K$-algebra $S$ generated by the $a_i$ is absolutely irreducible if and only if the group is. By Jacobson's density theorem, $S$ is a simple algebra, so $dim S\cdot\dim C=n^2$ by the double centralizer theorem. By Schur's Lemma, $C$ is a divison field over $K$. So if $C$ is bigger than the scalars, then there is a field $K<F\le C$. But then $S$ is reducible over $F$, hence not absolutely irreducible.

Comment: @YvesCornulier That sounds quite practical (except for the slight issue of this being a one-way algorithm -- if you keep getting smaller rank, how do you know when to give up)?

Comment: @PeterMueller your "completely reducible" hypothesis is over which domain? (sorry to be dense, this is a little new to me...)

Comment: PS: in the way I put it it looks quite not efficient (need to compute the image of the ball of radius 10000 if $n=100$). But in practice it's better: just define $V_0$ as the line generated by identity matrix, $V_{i+1}$ as the subspace spanned by the $se_j$, where $s$ ranges over the generating subset $S$ and $e_j$ ranges over a basis if $V_i$. Then compute a basis for $V_i$ and go ahead until $V_k=V_{k+1}$.

Comment: @Igor: the rank get larger until it reaches the dimension of the subspace spanned by $\rho(G)$. Whenever $V_i=V_{i+1}$, you know that $V_i$ is stable by the generators and hence is equal to $\rho(G)$. Hence the process gives a definite answer it at most $n^2$ answers whatever the answer is.

Comment: @YvesCornulier: The method you describe is not used in practical algorithms for finite groups, because its complexity of $O(n^6)$ field operations is prohibitive, particualrly if you aim to do computations with $n \sim 10^5$. But it is probably the easiest for general f.g. groups provided that $n$ is not too big.

Comment: @YvesCornulier Ah, I see, so this (as in your second version) is actually quite efficient (in each step you are computing the rank of a (less than) $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix, and you are doing this at most $n^2$ times, so around $n^8.$ Not quite blazing, but reasonable.

Comment: @DerekHolt Can you really do $O(n^6)?$

Comment: @DerekHolt And, by "easiest", do you mean "easiest to implement"? Do you know of a faster general algorithm (not using finite group-specific ideas)?

Comment: @Igor: I meant "completely reducible" over the base field.

Comment: Yes I meant easiest to implement. For groups that are not necessarily finite, I know nothing faster than the ideas suggested here by Peter and Yves.

Comment: @PeterMueller So, not the algebraic closure, is that right?

Comment: @Igor: Yes.$\phantom{}$

Comment: Since the discussions are entangled, just to pinpoint: I did not make any complete reducibility assumption.

Comment: @YvesCornulier Yes, I noticed that (which is why this is more attractive than Peter's method right now).

Comment: I also have the feeling that the algorithm should finish in much less than $n^2$ steps, at least when the group is indeed absolutely irreducible. I don't have a formal proof, but there are many expansion results (see e.g. Breuillard-Green-Tao or Pyber-Szabo) in groups and the algebra counterparts might be even easier, saying something like: if $V_{i+1}$ is not the whole algebra of matrices then it is much bigger than $V_i$ (say $\dim(V_{i+1})>\lambda\dim(V_i)$ for some $\lambda>1$... depending on $n$?). This is just a rough idea though.

Comment: @YvesCornulier Interesting thought. It should also be true that if you pick random $n^2$ elements from the $O(\log n)$-th "shell", they should span (but for that you might need stronger assumptions, something like that the Zariski closure of your group is semisimple). In fact, you might need something like that for your conjecture as well...

Comment: @IgorRivin: thinking twice: I guess in the worst case you need to go through the $n$-ball ($\log(n)$ is not enough): if you consider for large $n$ the 3-generated subgroup generated the unipotent $e_{12}$, $e_{21}$ and the shift (shifting cyclically the basis $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$, then it is clearly absolutely irreducible, but a ball of radius $o(n)$ will not span the whole algebra of matrices.

Comment: @YvesCornulier Hmm. More thought is required (especially as the group you generate, I believe, is the whole of $SL(n, \mathbb{Z}).$ In the meantime, would you happen to have a reference for your original statement (that absolute irreducibility is equivalent to the rank condition)?

Comment: @IgorRivin, Yves is using Burnside's theorem.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Thanks! I said I was new to this :)

Answer (score 1):

There are very complicated groups $G$ such that $G = \langle x,y : x^{2} = y^{3} = 1 \rangle,$ possibly with further relations. In a sense, the most complicated such group is ${\rm PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z}),$ which is the free product of a group of order $2$ and a group of order $3$.

For any given representation of such a group, it is easy to calculate the invariant subspaces of the generators, but calculating the invariant subspaces for the whole group seems hard to me.